# Как вернуть метод класса в методе string ToString() const

Tags: c++, классы, методы

`representationShape` - это строковое представление фигуры. В базовом интерфейсе IShape должен быть метод `std::string ToString() const`, возвращающий строковое представление фигуры.

> Ошибка    1   error C2662: std::string IShape::representationShape(void):
> невозможно преобразовать указатель "this" из "const IShape" в "IShape
> &"    21  1   ConsoleApplication2

Проблема исчезает если убрать const.

```
class IShape
{
public:
    virtual double square() = 0;
    virtual double perimeter() = 0;
    virtual string representationShape() = 0;
    string ToString() const
    {
        return representationShape();
    }
    virtual ~IShape();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не обязательно убирать можно и добавить:

```
virtual string representationShape() const = 0;
```

Проблема у вас в том, что ваш метод `representationShape()` объявлен как "*я верну `string`, и при этом изменю внутреннее состояние класса*". А

```
string ToString() const
```

как "*я верну `strng` и обещаю не менять внутреннее состояние класса*". Раз пообещал - надо выполнять и НЕ вызывать то, что может изменять объект.

Я думаю, что вы не собираетесь в `representationShape()` менять объект класса, поэтому можно добавить `const`. Но если собираетесь - ну, создавайте копию объекта в `ToString` и работайте с нею...